# How to use cryptocomapre api to display price of BTC?

Tags: api, electron, bitcoin

I'm working on an electron app and im using cryptocompare api to display BTC price but it dosen't displays. I've tried every solution i could think of, some help would be appreciated!!

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow;
const axios = require('axios');

const notifyBtn = document.querySelector('.notify-btn');
const price = document.querySelector('.price');
const targetPrice = document.querySelector('.target-price');

function  getBTC(){
    const cryptos = axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD&api_key={api_key}')
        price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos
    }

getBTC();
setInterval(getBTC, 20000);
```

It gives me an output of '$[object Promise]'

Answer (score -1):

In the documentation for axios, it says you need to do this instead:

```
axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        // do something with response
    });
```

This is because the value returned by `axios.get` isn't a response, it's a promise that will resolve to a response. (So it gets coerced to the string `[object Promise]`.) If you don't know what this means, read [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Basically promises are a way of dealing with tasks that take a long time to run (such as api calls) without blocking other javascript code from runnning. But anyway, what you want is this:

```
function  getBTC(){
    axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD&api_key={api_key}')
        .then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            var cryptos = // get cryptos from data somehow
            price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos;
        });
}
```

I haven't read the axios documentation in detail. I believe what you are looking for is in `response.data`, but I couldn't tell you any more than that. Try `console.log('Response:', response);` to find out how the response is structured.

Comment: Now Im getting $undefined.

Comment: That wasn't a complete answer, because I couldn't figure out all the details from the documentation. I meant that you need to find out how `response` is structured by logging it (or possibly by reading the docs more thoroughly than I did). Then you can replace the `var cryptos` line with something more sensible. Currently it's joining that line onto the next line because it doesn't end with a semicolon; so it's equivalent to `var cryptos; price.innerHTML = '$'+cryptos; cryptos = price.innerHTML;`. That's why it's setting the price to `$undefined`.